# 2 LCD screens 1 raspberry3B+

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-3b+, lcd

I got a raspberry pi 3 B+ and two small LCD screens, [this one](https://www.amazon.it/dp/B07NTH1JWH?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details) and [this one](https://www.amazon.it/dp/B07BQSTK2V?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details)

The first is attached on the gpio pins, the second one on the hdmi port

the problem is they are just mirroring each other, when I need two distinct monitors

**Is there a way to set up these two LCD screens to show two different desktops?**